# R - query all large text files in a folder without reading each file into Rstudio using vroom

Tags: r

I have a list of 15 txt files in a folder that are each 1.5 - 2 GB. Is there a way to query each file for specific rows based on a condition and then load the results into a list of data frames in R? Currently, I am loading a few files in at once using

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt");
data_list = lapply(temp, read.delim); names(data_list) = temp
```

and then applying a custom filter function to each of the data frames in the list using lapply.

Due to RAM limitations, I cannot load entire files into my R environment and then query. I'm looking for some code to perhaps automatically read in one file, perform the query, add the data frame result to a list, free up the memory, and then repeat. Thank you!

---

Edit:
It seems like I should use vroom instead of read.delim:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt");
data_list = lapply(temp, vroom); names(data_list) = temp
```

I get a few warning messages and when I run `problems()`,

I get:

```
Error in vroom_materialize(x, replace = FALSE) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Is this an issue?

Each of the files have a different number of columns, so do I need to use `map` as described [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/vroom-with-multiple-files-different-number-of-columns/52752/2)

Lastly, on each of the data frames in the list, I would like to run

```
filtered_list = lapply(data_list, filter, COL1 == "ABC")
```

Does doing so essentially read in each of the files, negating the benefits of vroom? When I run this `lapply`, R takes a very long time.

Comment: The *vroom* package might be of interest to you: https://vroom.r-lib.org/ - "*vroom doesn’t stop to actually read all of your data, it simply indexes where each record is located so it can be read later.*"

Comment: And `vroom` supports reading data from multiple files into a single data frame.

Comment: Thank you. Do I just replace ```read.delim``` with ```vroom```? I would like to run ```filtered_list = lapply(data_list, filter, COL1 == "ABC")``` on the list of data frames that loads. After loading in the files using ```vroom```, does querying each data frame using ```filter``` then require each data frame to be read into R? Running to ```lapply`` function seems to take a very long time.

Comment: To be honest, i'm not sure. I seemed to recall the package could also allow fast filtering but now I can't find any reference to that.

Comment: No worries, thank you for the suggestion - I will edit my question specifically for how to use vroom properly.

Comment: "*Filtering also can be fast, only the columns included in the filter selection have to be fully read and only the data in the filtered rows needs to be read from the remaining
columns.*" - https://github.com/tidyverse/vroom/blob/HEAD/vignettes/benchmarks.Rmd - so it sounds like if the filtering query can be simplified a bit it should be a bit quicker.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like this solution works as running a simple ```filter``` still takes a very long time. Additionally, some of the ```filter``` results return empty when I know that loading the full file into the environment and running ```filter``` returns results.

Comment: You might consider `read.csv.sql` from *sqldf* package as well - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sqldf/versions/0.4-11/topics/read.csv.sql